# Use native iOS camera filters with Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I would like to use the native camera filters and editing options (like red eyes correction) available on iOS 7 with iPhone 4S and further on my Cordova app using the Camera Plugin.

I remember I already managed to do it, but I can't remember how...

I've tried the `allowEdit: true` option but it only allows you to crop your image before uploading...

I'm turning really crazy because I'm 100% sure I already got it working on a former project, without even trying to, and people seems to say it's impossible...

Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I have been looking too. I looked into a library like filterousjs to apply filters using html and javascript but it is quite slow.